# How to access model attribute in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring, attributes

I want to access a model attribute in Javascript. I use the following code:

```
model.addAttribute("data", responseDTO);
```

My DTO class:

```
public class ResponseDTO {

    private List<ObjectError> errors;

    private Boolean actionPassed;

    private String dataRequestName;

    // and setter getter for all fields
}
```

I tried accessing the DTO using:

```
var data = "${data}";
```

But it is giving me a string representation of responseDTO instead, i.e `com.req.dto.ResponseDTO@115f4ea`. I can successfully access a field inside the DTO using:

```
 var data = "${data.actionPassed}";
```

But this is not working for the `errors` attribute inside the DTO, as it is a `List` of `ObjectError`. How can I get complete `responseDTO` object in Javascript?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT :**

Initially I was using `jquery.post`

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  // Here I was able to retrieve every attribute even list of ObjectError.
});
```

Now I want to remove Ajax and want to convert it into non-ajax approach (because of some unavoidable reasons). So I am doing a normal form submit and want load same form again and trying to load `data` model attribute in Javascript so that I can keep the rest of the code as it is.
I was wondering if it can be achieved in Javascript as it is doable using Jquery post?

---

**EDIT 2 :**

I tried (Thank you @Grant for suggestions)

```
JSONObject jsonObject =JSONObject.fromObject(responseDTO);
String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
model.addAttribute("data",jsonString);
```

and in Javascript

```
var data = eval('('+ ${dataJson} +')');   // Getting error on this line  
alert(data.actionPassed);
```

But getting error and no alert is displayed
Error :
[image]

Comment: Where do you want to access the object, within a JSP file or on client side after the DTO is returned by some AJAX call?

Comment: Before you continue, stop and consider: your model resides on the **server**, javascript happens on the **client**. Now, what is it you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Ralph: No I want to remove Ajax part. Please check my edit for more details.

Comment: @pap: Please check my edit and let me know if there is any right / better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, there's no way to convert a Java object to a Javascript object directly since they have nothing to do with each other. One is server-side language and the other is client-side language.
So to accomplish this goal, you have to do some convertion. I think you have two options:

1. Convert ResponseDTO object to JSON string and pass it to jsp and you may get the javascript object directly.
2. Pass ResponseDTO object to JSP and populate the javascript object as what you are trying now.

For option #1, you should use a library to generate JSON string by the Java object. You can use this one [JSON-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/).
e.g:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject( responseDTO );  
/*  
  jsonStr is something like below, "errors" represents the List<ObjectError>
  I don't know what's in ObjectError, errorName is just an example property.
  {
    "dataRequestName":"request1",
    "actionPassed":true,
    "errors":[{"errorName":"error"},{"errorName":"unknown error"}]
  } 
*/
String jsonStr = jsonObject.toString();
model.addAttribute("dataJson", jsonStr);  

/*In JSP, get the corresponding javascript object
 by eval the json string directly.*/
<script>
var data = eval('('+'${dataJson}'+')'); 
</script>
```

For option #2,

```
//Pass java object as you do now
model.addAttribute("data",responseDTO);

//In JSP, include jstl taglib to help accessing List.
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<script>
var errorArr = [], errorObj;
<c:forEach var="error" items="${data.errors}">
    errorObj = { errorName: '${error.errorName}' };
    errorArr.push(errorObj);                                  
</c:forEach>

//Populate the corresponding javascript object.
var data = {
  dataRequestName: '${data.dataRequestName}',
  actionPassed: ${data.actionPassed},
  errors: errorArr
};
</script>
```

As you can see, option #2 is complicated and only useful if the Java object is simple while option #1 is much easier and maintainable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing both easy and hard ways. In option #1 can I access all the attribute using `data.`? Also please check my edit I have added more details.

Comment: @Ajinkya Yes. You can access all attributes like using java object. The only difference is "errors" is represented as an array.  I'm not sure I understand your edit correctly..You said you were able to retrieve every attribute even list of ObjectError by jquery.post, so why is this question raised? What's in ajax/test.html ?

Comment: I was able to access it in Ajax callback ie in function defined in jquery post. but now I want to remove Ajax so I want access the model attribute in Javascript.

Comment: I did exactly same as you suggested. but getting error  `missing ) in parenthetical    
(NaN
Source File: http://localhost:7009/portal/request/form/submit
Line: 1011, Column: 4`
Source Code:
(NaN

Comment: @Ajinkya option 1 or 2? Could you give more details? what's in line 1011?

Comment: I tried option #1. Please check my edit. I have details about it.

Comment: @Ajinkya oh, sorry, missed the single quotes around ${dataJson}, should be: `eval('('+'${dataJson}'+')');` If dataJson is really a json string, this piece of code should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot man :) You saved my life (Even though I have created mess for myself)

Comment: Instead of eval() you could also use JSON.parse()

Answer (score 2):

So I just implemented a similar solution to Grant's first option  with a List of objects, but used the [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library to convert the object to a JSON string, then used JSON.parse() to turn it into a javascript object:

On the server:

```
List<CustomObject> foo = database.getCustomObjects();
model.addAttribute("foo", new Gson().toJson(foo));
```

In the page javascript:

```
var customObjectList = JSON.parse('${foo}');
console.log(customObjectList);
```

Notice that when I reference the model object foo, that I do so as a string '${foo}'.  I believe you are getting your error because you reference it outside of a string.  So the correct code would be:

```
var data = eval('('+ '${dataJson}' +')');
```

Comment: How would you deal with single quote characters in ${foo}? The JavaScript generated would end up as:
  
`var customObjectList = JSON.parse('{"foo":"bar's baz"}');`

which is invalid.

Using `fn:replace` is obvious, but also seems a bit hack-ish. Are there other special characters that need to be dealt with?

Answer (score 2):

its very simple

```
in your spring controller 

model.addAttribute("attributeName", "attributeValue");

in the script

<script type="text/javascript">      
     $(window).on('load', function () {             
            var springAttribute= '${attributeName}';
            alert(springAttribute);     
    </script>
```