# getting model attribute from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, addattribute

i'm going to send fileVO(java bean) to my js file. 
how to get this value from js?

model attribute from java.

```
   model.addAttribute("fileVO", fileVOListTmp.get(0));
```

and I need to get this value in javascript.

```
<script>
        var fileVO = $('#fileVO').val();
        alert(fileVO);

</script>
```

but it shows undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access model attribute in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361977/how-to-access-model-attribute-in-javascript)

Comment: what does the return output looks in DOM ? does the element has an Id of "fileVO" ? if not then it will never return the value that you are trying to get.