# Access to model addatribute in javascript spring MVC

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-boot, model-view-controller

Here(Controller) I add an attibute to my model

```
@RequestMapping("/archivosProcesados")
public String archivosProcesados(final ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("allfiles", filestorageService.getAllFiles());
    return "archivosprocesados";
}
```

and in my view I access to them via Thymeleaf like this

```
            <tr th:each="ap: ${archivos}">
                <td th:text="${ap.clave_documento}"></td>
                <td th:text="${ap.tipo_documento}"></td>
                <td th:text="${ap.nombre_documento}"></td>
                <td th:text="${ap.fecha_procesamiento}"></td>
            </tr>
```

so I want to access to same values in my javaScript code, but how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do that Convert Java object to JSON string and pass it to thymeleaf and you will get the javascript object directly.

Refer this [How to access model attribute in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361977/how-to-access-model-attribute-in-javascript)

and

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart

Comment: Thansk a lot I finally understand