# Send object from Java backend to JavaScript frontend via model

Tags: javascript, java, spring, model

I am trying to pass some objects from Java backend to the JavaScript frontend as following:

WeightController:

```java
String jsonString = new JSONObject()
   .put("weightEntry", weightEntry).toString();

model.addAttribute("weightEntry", jsonString);
```

using the following library to create a json:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20220320</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "WeightEntry")
public class WeightEntry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "weightEntry")
    private Set<Image> imageSet = new HashSet<>();

    private double weight;
    private Date date;

    public WeightEntry() {}
}
```

```html
<script>
    var obj = eval('('+'${weightEntry}'+')'); //this is not working
    var obj2 = [[${weightEntry}]] //this shows blank??
</script>
```

I found this on stackoverflow which is outdated (it seems)
[How to access model attribute in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361977/how-to-access-model-attribute-in-javascript)

Comment: That `var obj2 = [[${weightEntry}]] ;` line looks like [Thymeleaf JavaScript inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#javascript-inlining) to me. But (a) that would require you to use  `<script th:inline="javascript">` (not `<script>`); and (b) is your Spring project even using Thymeleaf in the first place? Possibly not... And, having said all that, the underlying problem could be something else entirely.